# How do you move up within a single line that's word-wrapped in vim?

Tags: vim

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Look at the image above, it is one line that declares a huge list. Now suppose my cursor is on the first element's `'i'` and I press 'j' then the cursor directly goes to the line `new_s=''` but what I want is the cursor go to the 's' of the word `'she'` below `'i'`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`j` moves the cursor down one *physical line*. You can use `gj` to move down one *displayed line*.

Answer (score 8):

The existing answers are spot on.

I wanted to add that `j`/`k` and `gj`/`gk` are strictly equivalent when you are working on non-wrapped text. Thus, the following mappings are as harmless (if you don't `:set wrap`) as they are useful (if you `:set wrap`):

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

Comment: Vim rookie here. I'll have to look into what nnoremap means :)

Comment: It can be called "non-recursive mapping", see [this page](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I like the script from here:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping
" mapping to make movements operate on 1 screen line in wrap mode

> function! ScreenMovement(movement)
>     if &wrap && b:gmove == 'yes'
>       return "g" . a:movement
>     else
>       return a:movement
>     endif
>   endfunction
>   onoremap   j ScreenMovement("j")
>   onoremap   k ScreenMovement("k")
>   onoremap   0 ScreenMovement("0")
>   onoremap   ^ ScreenMovement("^")
>   onoremap   $ ScreenMovement("$")
>   nnoremap   j ScreenMovement("j")
>   nnoremap   k ScreenMovement("k")
>   nnoremap   0 ScreenMovement("0")
>   nnoremap   ^ ScreenMovement("^")
>   nnoremap   $ ScreenMovement("$")
>   vnoremap   j ScreenMovement("j")
>   vnoremap   k ScreenMovement("k")
>   vnoremap   0 ScreenMovement("0")
>   vnoremap   ^ ScreenMovement("^")
>   vnoremap   $ ScreenMovement("$")
>   vnoremap   j ScreenMovement("j")
>   " toggle showbreak
>   function! TYShowBreak()
>     if &showbreak == ''
>       set showbreak=>
>     else
>       set showbreak=
>     endif
>   endfunction
>   let b:gmove = "yes"
>   function! TYToggleBreakMove()
>     if exists("b:gmove") && b:gmove == "yes"
>       let b:gmove = "no"
>     else
>       let b:gmove = "yes"
>     endif
>   endfunction
>   nmap   ,b  TYShowBreak()
>   nmap   ,bb  TYToggleBreakMove()

You can then use ,b to display if the line wraps (above example uses '>' character).
Then ,bb turns off screen movement if you have wrap set

Additionally I have wrapping set to a binding in my VIMRC as well:

```
"--- wrap toggle with f2 key---"
function! ToggleWrap()
set wrap!|set wrap?
endfunction

"F2 toggles wrap
nmap <f2> :call ToggleWrap()<CR>
vmap <F2> <C-C>:call ToggleWrap()<CR>
imap <F2> <C-O>:call ToggleWrap()<CR>i
```

Answer (score 2):

My behavior with Vim was a bit different, perhaps because of the options it is compiled with. On this version, line navigation with `j` and `k` would navigate one physical line by default, i.e. what typing `gj` and `gk` would do. Unexplained, and possibly for some other reason, it appears to only to do so on Unix files, DOS files would still navigate the full line, i.e. the multiple-physical, word-wrapped ones.

To get `j` and `k` to navigate only physical lines for all files, I had to set all these in my `.vimrc` to get the expectant behavior:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
vnoremap j gj
vnoremap k gk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type gj the cursor will move one line down, gk brings you one line up.
I assume that you are in a normal console window?

Cheers